# Optimality Conditions for Linearly Constrained Problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have the following optimization problem:

$min$ $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$

$s.t.$

$x_1+2x_2+3x_3\geq 4$

$x_3\leq 1$

It is asked without solving the KKT system, prove the problem has a unique optimal solution and it satisfies the KKT conditions.

Objective is quadratic $x^TQx$, and $Q$ is equal to the identity matrix which is positive definite. Therefore, the objective function is strictly convex. As the constraint is linear, it is convex too. I thought the answer should be related to those facts, but couldn't find it.

Comment: can you prove it by contradiction, using strict convexity as an argument?

Comment: Hey @LinAlg , thanks a lot! I did that and proved the uniqueness of the optimal solution. But stuck on the second part. How do you think I can show the unique solution satisfies the KKT conditions?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_(or_constraint_qualifications)